# How to open 100000 different websites manually

Tags: web-scraping, scrape

I need to click in 100000 different url from websites to scrape different data about the website. The data has to be manually extracted because it is different on each website and it doesn't follow a pattern.

My question is, is there any program or script where I can paste the 100000 URL and it just open/preload some urls in tabs/windows so when I close one tab the next url opens in a new tab? This way I work in the main website tab that takes me 10 seconds to review and I click control+w and go to the next url.

This way I could save so much time instead of just clicking manually on each link and waiting for it to load.

Comment: Have a look at *phantomjs*

Answer (score 1):

You can use python web scraping or RPA(if you don't know basic python) and by logical steps, users can automate n number of tasks to be done.
Or you can also make use of 'pyautogui library' of python to click on visual things.

Thumbs up. If helped...